# Download Blob_file with SAS

Tags: excel, sas, ms-office

I am trying to download Blob file from ORACLE DB. I used dbms_lob.substr to cut binary data on parts (max length of HEX field is 2,000). So I cut it, then I put data into .docx file. When I open it I see the message:

> Word found a problem with content in file test777.docx

and asks me to repair the file. After the Office suite repairs, the document just opens fine. I am able to open the document.

The core problem I think in a screenshot:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

After cutting remained quantity of a symbol of the last field is it is supplemented by '02'. So when I write it in a file and open it with binary view I see lots of spaces in there. As I understand that is a core problem.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

1. Does anyone knows how to avoid it? I think the problem in method of downloading.
2. How to repair bunch of files like Office does? (I have nearly 100 files every month).

Comment: You need to show the code you used to download and write out the object.  SAS character variables are always padded with spaces, so when writing the value you need to make sure to use a format like `$VARYING.` that will make sure to only write the valid characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify a variable name for the length of the blob so I will use BLOB_LENGTH.  You need to make sure not to write out more than the full length.  Also you do not want the MOD option on the FILE statement since you are creating the file not appending to an existing file.

```
data _null_; 
  length fv $ 120; 
  set blobs; 
  fv="k:\Folder\"||File_nm; 
  file writeout FILEVAR=fv recfm=n; 
  array blob[8] blob_1-blob_8; 
  do i=1 to 8 ;
    len = max(0,min(2000,blob_length - 2000*(i-1)));
    put blob[i] $varying2000. len; 
  end;
run;
```

Comment: WOW thanks. Will it works for example If the end ob the file will be on Blob_7 but I will have blob_8 on the code?

Comment: Yes. It will set LEN to 0 and the PUT statement will write 0 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. Can I have your contact? I want to thank you.

Comment: Note sure about how StackOverFlow contacts work. Try on SAS communities.  https://communities.sas.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/159

Comment: Tom hi. If there is two files with the same name will I have to different files? Or they will overwrite?

Comment: Try it and see. If the records are next to each other so that value of FV variable doesn't change then the data would be appended into the same file.  If there is a different file in between I am not sure if it would append or overwrite.

Comment: Its overwrite if the file name the same.   Does this code have an option not to overwrite it? Thank you!

Comment: I would change the logic for either how you select the records or how you generate the output filename to eliminate the duplicates.  Is there not another field that distinguishes the rows that you could use when generating the filename?